# Excel - Determine if the zeros in a range of cells are part of the result or not

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently trying to automate a step counter for a centre of gravity data set in Excel.

The data provided is in three columns. Column 1 contains the time (always in steps of 5), while columns 2 & 3 contain the values for the x-axis and y-axis. These values create a line for the way the person's centre of gravity was shifting during a range of steps (data is always either right or left foot).

[image]

The different steps (most take about 20 steps per side) in the dataset can be seen by the large range of zeros (probably around 70 in a row) before the data starts again. So if both columns have numbers, we are in step 1. If both columns have about 70 zeros each, then we are in the pause. As soon as the numbers start again, we are in step 2. This is the beginning of a new step:

[image]

I was asked to create a formula to automate the step detection. Since there are large gaps between the numbers where the sensors only detect 0's, this wasn't too much of a problem. I'm sure it can be done better but my understanding is limited. This is my formula, the initial 1 is manual but then it recognises step 1 (indicated as 2):

[image]

However, on further inspection of the dataset across different subjects I realised that even within the step there are sometimes one or more zeros after which the 'normal' numbers continue. These zeros are important because they indicate that the centre of gravity is shifting away from the observed foot. My formula would now detect the beginning of a new step, which is wrong because we are still in the same step, even though the centre of gravity has briefly changed. As you can see the zeros are part of the steps but obviously the formula thinks a new step has started:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw1QN.png]

There are only 50 subjects, so it would be possible to adjust manually as the formula does a lot of the work.

However, I'm wondering if there's an intelligent way to adjust the formula to recognise that if the range of zeros is less than 10 rows then we're still in the same step, but if the range is greater then we're in the pause.

Initially, I added a CountIF condition where if there is only one zero in three rows, the new step should be ignored and the old one kept. But since the centre shift usually takes more than three lines, but never more than five, I'm at a loss as to whether such a detection would be possible at all. An example of quick centre shift that takes three lines bevore the sensor picks the activity back up:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. So you just need to count the number of consecutive zeros and if that count is more than 10, then it means it's a new step?

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well as the edit! :) Yes, if the consecutive zeros would be larger than 10 it would be a new step, otherwise it is still the same step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty challenging your need. I was not able to do a formula without manual input. Best approach I could get is you need to set up manually the **first 10 rows** of your data with the value of step (or blank if that zero is not part of a step).

[image]

Cells from B1 to B10 are manual inputs: 1 because those values would be step 1 and blank because those zeros would **not** be part of step 1. Then in cell B11 i got this formula:

```
=IF(A11<>0;IF(B10="";MAX($B$1:B10)+1;MAX($B$1:B10));IF(COUNTIF(A1:A10;0)+COUNTIF(A12:A21;0)>=10;"";MAX($B$1:B10)))
```

Notice I've highlighted in yellow 8 consecutive zeros. Because 8 is less than 10 the formula thinks it's still the same step. The formula returns blank for zeros not belonging to any step, so it's easier to see each step

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you very much :) 
This improves the current step detection by a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Fill the first ten cells in the D column with the value 1, then:
`=IF(SUM(B2:B11)>0,D11,IF(B12=0,D11,D11+1))` for the rest of the lines.

(if any of the previous ten lines were non-zero, stay on the same step; if the current line is zero, als stay on the same step, otherwise go to the next step.)

Answer (score 0):

place:

- in cell E1 the number of consecutive "zero" rows delimiting a step
- in cell D2 the following formula

  ```
   =IF(SUM(OFFSET(B2;-MIN(ROW()-1;$E$1);0;MIN(ROW()-1;$E$1);2))=0;MAX($D$1:D1)+1;D1)
  ```

and drag it down

[image]
[image]